# React Material UI - Responsive CardMedia

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design, material-ui

Currently, I am trying to build a gallery using React Material UI (with [Card](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/), ...).
I have some issues to make the gallery responsive, as I might have different cover sizes :

[image]

Here is the code I used :

My card implementation :

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    gameRoot: {
        position: "relative",
        height: "100%"
    },
    gameCover: {
        zIndex: 1
    }
}));

function CardEntry(props) {
    const {game} = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    function watchGame() {
       // some redirecting stuff not needed for this POC
    }

    return (
        <Card className={classes.gameRoot}>

                <CardActionArea onClick={watchGame}>
                    <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        className={classes.gameCover}
                        image={game.imagePath}
                        title={game.title}
                    />
                </CardActionArea>
            
        </Card>
    );

}

export default CardEntry;
```

Which is called by the HOC Gallery I have :

```
import React from "react";

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import CardEntry from "./CardEntry";

// To dynamically change the number of items depending of browser
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    // inspired by the settings https://www.youtube.com/gaming uses ;)
    gameEntry: {
        // 2 items on [0, sm]
        [theme.breakpoints.only('xs')]: {
            "flex-basis": "calc((100% / 2) - 1%)"
        },
        // 4 items on [sm, md[
        [theme.breakpoints.only('sm')]: {
            "flex-basis": "calc((100% / 4) - 1%)"
        },
        // 8 items on [md, infinity]
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            "flex-basis": "calc((100% / 8) - 1%)"
        },
    }
}));

// The gallery component
function GamesGallery(props) {
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const currentGames = [/*See comment below*/]

    return (
        <Grid
            container
            spacing={1}
            style={
                {
                    rowGap: "15px"
                }
            }
        >
            {
                currentGames
                    .map(game => 
                            <Grid 
                                key={game.playlistId ?? game.videoId} 
                                item 
                                className={classes.gameEntry}
                            >
                                <CardEntry game={game}/>
                            </Grid>
                    )
            }
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

For testing, here is some data (with corner cases) I could have in `currentGames` variable :

```json
[
   {
      "title": "Astérix & Obélix XXL",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ7hPe8RxhK3FTXoqdFNL0BG/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ7hPe8RxhK3FTXoqdFNL0BG"
   },
   {
      "title": "Astérix & Obélix XXL 2",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ6FTJ2LSrdL4MaFM1Pl5nfo/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ6FTJ2LSrdL4MaFM1Pl5nfo"
   },
   {
      "title": "Astérix & Obélix XXL 2 : Mission Ouifix",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ6lDdIcNMFKsCzWtItCEcBq/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ6lDdIcNMFKsCzWtItCEcBq"
   },
   {
      "title": "Beyond Good & Evil",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ7GRN3EnqBEvfki5uAKiw5Z/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ7GRN3EnqBEvfki5uAKiw5Z"
   },
   {
      "title": "Bully",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ4l1G59ZVCUuTuZ-btLpPnm/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ4l1G59ZVCUuTuZ-btLpPnm"
   },
   {
      "title": "Chicken Invaders 5 - Cluck of the dark side",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ5x3Al4O71diHmivHNIRn2B/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ5x3Al4O71diHmivHNIRn2B"
   },
   {
      "title": "Guns Gore & Cannoli",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ6oiHK7lfTbOQlMWVHecx2I/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ6oiHK7lfTbOQlMWVHecx2I"
   },
   {
      "title": "Guns Gore & Cannoli 2",
      "imagePath": "https://jy95.github.io/yt_gaming_library/covers/PLRfhDHeBTBJ4ivg1J2leFzeuABXobVFNO/cover.webp",
      "playlistId": "PLRfhDHeBTBJ4ivg1J2leFzeuABXobVFNO"
   }
]
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: just to be clear, what do you mean by responsive? do you want the heights of the Cards to change based on the photo sizes? do you want the Cards to sit in neat rows or to slide up to fill available space in each column?

Comment: I would like the images to fit the size available to them (so that there is no difference in size between each card) : object-fit doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand your main purpose correctly, modifying `MuiCardActionArea-root` and `CardMedia-root` will solve your problem. Please also check these two links about overriding styles and cardActionArea api in material-ui.
https://material-ui.com/customization/components/
https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/

Here is the corrected code that will solve your problem:

```
`CaedEntry.js`

import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    gameRoot: {
        position: "relative",
        height: "100%"
    },
    gameCover: {
        zIndex: 1,
        height: "inherit"
    },
    MuiCardActionArea:{
        height: "inherit",
        zIndex: 1
    }
}));

function CardEntry(props) {
    const {game} = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    function watchGame() {
       // some redirecting stuff not needed for this POC
    }

    return (
        <Card className={classes.gameRoot}>

                <CardActionArea classes={{root: classes.MuiCardActionArea}} onClick={watchGame}>
                    <CardMedia
                        component="img"
                        classes={{root: classes.gameCover}}
                        image={game.imagePath}
                        title={game.title}
                    />
                </CardActionArea>
            
        </Card>
    );

}

export default CardEntry;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) I found strange that object-fit didn't work at the first place